# What is the URL for the Stack Overflow error page?

Tags: support, 500-server-error

Where can I find the URL to the error page with the kitten picture? I was trying to find it for a demonstration, and for the life of me, I can't seem to.

I guess that is a compliment, too?

Comment: See also [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error
- https://stackoverflow.com/error
- https://serverfault.com/error