# List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, faq, hidden-features

Here is a list of special, unlinked pages (they may be linked in questions and answers) on Stack Exchange sites. Most pages listed here are work in progress or legacy. Currently, this list is incomplete.

If you know more of them, add them to the answer.

*Related [Hidden features of Stack Exchange?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange)*

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: You know, if you *link* to them here, they won't be *unlinked* anymore... STOP INVALIDATING YOUR OWN TITLE!

Comment: @Shog9 [Catch 22!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22)

Answer (score 138):

## Global pages

#### Site list

- `/topbar/site-switcher/site-list`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/topbar/site-switcher/site-list](//stackoverflow.com/topbar/site-switcher/site-list)

  - Can be accessed from any site, with identical contents
  - Contains non-meta sites and the meta site for the Stack Exchange site from which it was requested
  - HTML format
- `/topbar/site-switcher/all-pinnable-sites`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/topbar/site-switcher/all-pinnable-sites](//stackoverflow.com/topbar/site-switcher/all-pinnable-sites)

  - Can be accessed from any site, with identical contents
  - Contains all SE sites, both main sites and meta sites
  - JSON format

    - A list of Objects, each describing a site
    - Example site Object:

      ```json
      {
          "title":"3d printing meta",
          "description":"",
          "sitename":"3D Printing Meta",
          "hostname":"3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com",
          "siteid":641
      }
      ```

#### Hot questions in JSON format

- https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-json

  - A textual overview of the current Hot Network Questions, for use by applications
  - JSON format (need to parse it manually)
  - Was previously located at `/hot-questions-for-mobile`, as it was created to be used by the mobile apps to show hot questions. [Since November 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/mobile-app-infrastructure-being-decommissioned#comment1280012_383125), has been relocated to its current URL, with the old URL kept as a redirect.

## Site-wide pages

#### Site moderator elections

- `/election`, e.g., [stackoverflow.com/election](//stackoverflow.com/election)

  - points to the ongoing election if there is one; shows a summary of past elections otherwise

#### The error page

- `/error`, e.g. [http://stackoverflow.com/error](//stackoverflow.com/error)

#### The Captcha pages

- `/captcha`, e.g., [stackoverflow.com/captcha](//stackoverflow.com/captcha)

  - used to show the traditional captcha puzzle in which one must decipher letters, is now the same as `/nocaptcha`
- `/nocaptcha`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/nocaptcha](//stackoverflow.com/nocaptcha)

  - shows the "no-CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA", which one has to check the "I'm not a robot" box and possibly solve a picture puzzle

#### Page not found

- `/404`, e.g., [stackoverflow.com/404](//stackoverflow.com/404)

#### Greatest Hits

- `/questions/greatest-hits`, e.g., [stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits](//stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits)

#### Annotated Posts

- `/annotated-posts`, e.g., [stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts](//stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts)

#### Questions from deleted accounts

- `/questions?filters=DeactivatedUsers`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/questions?filters=DeactivatedUsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?filters=DeactivatedUsers)

  - Shows posts from users with anonymized profiles.
  - Normally only linked to for team admins in SO for Teams

#### Debug homepage

- `/home/recommended/debug`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/home/recommended/debug](//stackoverflow.com/home/recommended/debug)

  - The debug homepage, from the time the recommended homepage was being tested, see [Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 3 - algorithm tweaks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271128/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-3-algorithm-tweaks)

#### jQuery fallback cookie

- `/home/get-jquery-fallback-cookie`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/home/get-jquery-fallback-cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/home/get-jquery-fallback-cookie)

  - Link is only shown when external scripts fail to load from `ajax.googleapis.com`. Sets a cookie on one's browser to load the scripts from another source.

#### Advice page

- `/questions/ask/advice`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice)

  - Only shown on certain sites for first question askers; once one checks the box it will never show again for that user.

#### Ask a question with pre-filled tags

- `/questions/ask?tags=[tag names separated by +]`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=javascript+html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=javascript+html)

#### Force standard homepage

- `/?questions`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/?questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?questions)

  - On sites with custom homepages for logged-out users (currently only Stack Overflow), forces the standard "question list" homepage

#### Active tab

- `/?tab=active`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/?tab=active](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=active)

  - On sites with a different default homepage from the "active" tab used on most sites (currently only Stack Overflow), forces the active tab, which is not available as a tab option with the new homepage tab design.
  - This also forces the old homepage for logged-out users; it's not necessary to use something like `?questions&tab=active` (although that also works).

#### All Collectives™ articles (Stack Overflow only)

- https://stackoverflow.com/articles

#### Beta access (Area 51 only)

- https://area51.stackexchange.com/beta-access

  - Incorrectly claims Area 51 is in private beta
  - Allows entering an unknown password to access Area 51

## Per-user information

For the items in this section, you must be logged in, and you get the data corresponding to your account.

#### Personal reputation report

- `/reputation`, e.g., [stackoverflow.com/reputation](//stackoverflow.com/reputation)

  - Plain text format
  - Also known as reputation audit page or reputation report page, more details [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation).

#### Inbox

- `/topbar/inbox`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox](//stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox) (same content on any site)

  - can be accessed from any site, with identical contents
  - HTML format
- `/topbar/achievements`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/topbar/achievements](//stackoverflow.com/topbar/achievements)

  - can be accessed from any site, with identical contents
  - HTML format

#### Tag prediction

- `/users/tag-future/current`, e.g., [stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current](//stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current)

  - analyzes which tags you prefer or avoid to answer ([related Meta post](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/194505))
  - The engine [hasn't been re-trained since January 2014](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/238638).

#### Network flair of any user

- `https://stackexchange.com/users/[network account ID]/?tab=flair`, e.g. https://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=flair

  - network flair showing all accounts; works on all accounts, not just your own account; old method of obtaining code
  - This flair is still supported, but the "preferred" way of obtaining the code is through the settings page on a specific site, rather than on the network profile

#### Flags declined in the last seven days

- `/users/flag-summary/current?showDeclined=true` e.g., [meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current?showDeclined=true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current?showDeclined=true)

  - a hidden view of your flag history that shows the flags you cast that were declined in the last seven days.
  - The link to this view is shown only to users who are banned from flagging because too many of the flags handled within the last seven days were declined.

#### Flag history

- `/users/flag-summary/current`

  - your personal flag history
  - This page is unlinked for users with less than 15 reputation, or who are suspended.

#### Privileges of any user

- `/help/privileges/user/[user ID]`, e.g. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/user/86

## Post information

#### Question revision history

- `/posts/[post ID]/revisions`, e.g., [meta.stackexchange.com/posts/76569/revisions](//meta.stackexchange.com/posts/76569/revisions)

  - shown as the “history” link for questions and answers with at least two revisions
  - contains links to individual revisions and their source code, as well as summaries of a number of other events such as closing, reopening, (un)deleting, bounty start/end, (un)locking, tweeting, marked (not) community wiki, and merging.

#### Votes page

- `/posts/[post ID]/votes`, e.g. [meta.stackexchange.com/posts/74983/votes](//meta.stackexchange.com/posts/74983/votes)

  - a JSON representation of your personal upvote or downvote towards the post

#### Comments page

- `/posts/[post ID]/comments`, e.g. [meta.stackexchange.com/posts/74983/comments](//meta.stackexchange.com/posts/74983/comments)

  - a textual representation of the comments on a given post

#### Individual review items

- `/review/[review type]/[review ID]`, e.g., [stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5375800](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5375800)

  - You can [find your own suggested edits](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/92602/).
  - Or [find the ID of an arbitrary review item](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/248286/).

- Recent reviews can be found easily with the [10k tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

#### Short URLs for comments

- `/posts/comments/[comment ID]`, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/1612336](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/1612336)

  - To get a shorter URL for a comment, get the comment ID from the full URL. For example, in the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#comment1612336_1732454`, the comment ID is `1612336`. Replace the "[comment ID]" in the above template with that.

## Chat-related pages

#### Recent messages, extended history

- A user's "recent" chat messages tab has hidden pagination.  Merely add `&page={N}` to the end of the URL.
  e.g.: [chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=recent&page=86](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=recent&page=86)

#### List of pingable users in a room

- `/rooms/pingable/[room number]` e.g. [chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/pingable/89](//chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/pingable/89)

  - JSON format (array of objects)
  - Each room has a list of users who can be @-pinged, who are the users currently in the room, or who have been in the room in the last 7 days and posted in that room at least once in the past.

#### Raw HTML content of a message

- `chat.stackexchange.com/message/<message_id>`; e.g. [chat.stackexchange.com/message/32533704](//chat.stackexchange.com/message/32533704) is the raw HTML of [this message](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32533704#32533704).

  - Plain text format (HTML)
  - If you append `?plain=true` to the end of the URL, you get raw Markdown (see below)

#### User-typed content of a message

- `chat.stackexchange.com/messages/<room_id>/<message_id>`; e.g. [chat.stackexchange.com/messages/240/32533704](//chat.stackexchange.com/messages/240/32533704) is what the user that posted [this message](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32533704#32533704) typed.

  - Plain text format (Markdown)
  - Also available via `chat.stackexchange.com/message/<message_id>?plain=true`

#### Chat profile for a given network profile

- `chat.stackexchange.com/account/<network_profile_id>`; e.g. [chat.stackexchange.com/account/1](//chat.stackexchange.com/account/1) redirects to the chat profile of [stackexchange.com/users/1](//stackexchange.com/users/1)

  - Obtains the chat profile corresponding to a specific user's stackexchange.com network profile

#### List of recent chat flags (moderator only)

- `/admin/recent-flags` - [Per-server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264527) basic list of messages flagged.

  - Requires you to have a recognized diamond on that chat server.
  - Only shows you flags that are visible to you (some flags are not visible to all moderators)

Comment: How do you know `/404` is actually an unlinked page, rather than just a non-existent page that therefore gives a 404 error?

Comment: True, http://stackoverflow.com/8675309 gives me the same page...

Comment: moderator agreement is linked from Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I don't think we should put here privileges/reputation based links. This is not the purpose of this faq as far as I can see. Removed your addition.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος in the [review page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review), which on turn is linked from the top bar.

Comment: As for edit wars, there's no "legal" or "illegal" - it's matter of who has more patience, and moderator will eventually come over and lock the post anyway. (as it raise automatic flag.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The review page isn't linked for everyone, though.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος there's no "everyone" mentioned here. This specific question is for pages unlinked anywhere, to anyone. That's its one and single purpose. If we start making it reputation based, we should also add the "flag" option (seen only when you have 15 reputation), bounty which is 75 etc. NOT what this question is about.

Comment: Technically the annotated posts page (`/annotated-posts`) is actually linked from the `/admin/links` page (as I've just been informed), but that latter links page is only visible to mods even though the annotated posts page is visible to everyone.

Comment: The `/election` page is actually linked from the [badge descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) (I guess it should also be linked somewhere else on a site during election so people could participate easily). Also 5 of these links can be accessed freely through a top/side bar (and 1 through comments), so there's not much point in them. And the tag prediction doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Wow - the greatest hit probably got 251,610 rep from a luckily-timed question about GitHub.