# Redirect old user page to new one

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, 404-not-found

I got some little icon on my Chrome bar (a Chrome plug) that when I click it it takes me to my questions located at:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/147955

However this is now a 404.  Can you please make a redirect to the new relevant page?  I kinda like my button as it is and don't want to have to remove it from my toolbar :(

Comment: Broken links are the cornerstone of the Internet

Comment: Right-click, edit?

Comment: @Arjan, it's a plugin for chrome, not a bookmark

Comment: Can you find the plugin script and edit it?

Comment: If that plugin is on http://stackapps.com, then maybe report there (too)?

Comment: Tom this sounds more like feature request.. it's not a bug as it's by design: the `/recent` page had limited time that expired by now, it was discussed several times here on Meta. Anyway, making it redirect to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/[user id here]?tab=reputation` sounds like valid request indeed..

Comment: @Shadow thanks changed to feat req

Comment: @Rup, can't be bothered/dont know how

Comment: @Tom cheers, added also a relevant tag, I would also change the title  but not sure, prefer you'll do it. :)

Comment: When adding new redirects, then instead of `/users/recent/` I'd rather see something like `/recent` or `/activity`, and without any user id. (Just [like](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites) `/reputation`, `/privileges` and `/inbox` show personal data.)