# FAQ for how to access question's timeline

Tags: feature-request, timeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post)

Could we get a addition to the FAQ that tells how to access a question's timeline? Several users have expressed a desire to see the all votes (negative and positive), and this is a simple solution, but a not so simple solution to find currently.

i.e. meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/125170/timeline

Comment: do you speacking about like: User X vote up at dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm? or you want "only" Vote Up received at dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm?

Comment: I am wanting publicity to the timeline feature for each question asked on StackExchange.

Comment: See [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites) - if they're not advertised more than that, there probably are reasons (the timeline view is probably pretty expensive to generate for instance)

Comment: @Mat could be. How did you find that list? where was it published on the site?

Comment: Try typing "\[faq\] timeline" (without the quotes) in the search box on this site, @SamStar

Comment: Timeline view of revision and vote history

[site name]/posts/[question number]/timeline
E.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/74983/timeline
applies to questions only, but shows information about the answers as well

Comment: Got here from Google. Didn't see an answer... So I copy+pasted from the linked dupe.

Comment: I googled for "activity log" and found nothing.  Now that I found out what term to use by other means (asking another user :-) this was my top search hit.  I'm vaguely hoping that adding my terminology here in a comment would make this easier to find in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Several users have expressed a desire to see the all votes (negative and positive)

There's an even simpler solution, and it is already explained on the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user).

Once you reach 1,000 reputation, you can click on the total vote score displayed by any post to break the score down into the actual vote counts, given as the number of upvotes and downvotes.

[image]

I don't think the timeline view has earned "official feature" status yet, that's why it hasn't made it into the public user interface. It also provides a whole lot of confusing and unnecessary information for the typical viewer, so I'm not sure that more effort should really be put into promoting it. If people are active on Meta and need/want this information, well then it's available.

If, for whatever reason, you like to view this information frequently and want to make it even easier to access, you can install a user script that does just that. For example, [this one](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) adds a "timeline" link to the list of links displayed below each question.

I used to have it installed when I first came across it because it seemed like a neat novelty. I hardly ever used it, and I therefore haven't even bothered to install it again after reloading that machine.

Comment: True, but that isn't an option for many SO users. Interesting info on timeline, I'd still like to see it make it to the FAQs. Thanks!

Comment: When the votes occurred is also interesting to see.  Fortunately, a new timeline is [allegedly in the works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270438/shouldnt-the-timeline-view-show-votes-that-have-been-removed#comment876313_270438).

Comment: Regarding the *"official feature" status*, are there any updates 4 years later?

Comment: Not that I know of, @Christian. 4 years may have passed, but very little of that time was spent working on the core Q&A engine, unfortunately. The timeline view is still easily accessible via a bit of URL manipulation. For any post, https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/125170/timeline is the timeline.

Comment: I don't think breaking down the votes is as useful as time-line. A time-line is useful in and of itself for checking when you made an edit.