# Is there any way to see upvote and downvote history on my question page in Meta Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

I just came from outside and saw my question has +3 points , when I opened the question page it has no upvotes and downvotes does not able to know how those points earned.

Later I went to my home page and opened Reputation tab and found that one upvote (+5) and one downvote(-2) given and thus it came to 3 points.

Is there any option to view this on my page itself if not Can I expect a feature to show this history or points on my question page itself?

I really linke the answer by Lix,

It would be great if we have option to add timeline link to our question/answer page so that we don't have to open another browser/tab and write this big url again.

Comment: Greasemonkey/Chrome script time!

http://stackapps.com/questions/2371/add-imeline-and-evisions-links

Comment: i don't know how to run the script, it will take time for me to learn.

Comment: Use either chrome or firefox. If you use firefox, install Greasemonkey. Now go to that page and find the install link. Done.

Comment: install link shows an script file how to install it. i am searching for Greasemonkey

Comment: Which browser are you using? Firefox? Greasemonkey inly works in FF https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: The install link should automatically install the script if you are using chrome or firefox+greasemonkey

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `timeline` feature to see this info.
Lets take this post as an example - 
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127376/`

What you'll need to do is substitute `questions` with `posts` and then truncate everything after the post id and add `/timeline` -

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/127376/timeline

Comment: +1 for introducing me to a new feature. Is this publicised anywhere?

Comment: Indeed it was mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view) but AFAIK there is no documentation of this feature...

Comment: +1 from me to, it would be great if we have option to add timeline link to our question/answer page so that we don't have to open another browser/tab and write this big url again.

Comment: See here for more possibly new features :P [List of unlinked pages on SE sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: @raveturned and Lix - and many more over here! [Hidden features of Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow) :)

Comment: @sha - well now we have to change the tile... its no longer hidden :P

Comment: @ImranRizvi [already suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/where-is-the-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post) - feel free to upvote so it might get implemented. :-D

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I already upvoted both the answers , unfortunatly I can't upvote my own question :-)

Comment: @ImranRizvi your own question is pretty much resolved.. no need to make it dupe of existing request.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd oh now I understood, upvoted your link

Answer (score 2):

A breakdown of upvotes and downvotes does exist, but it is only available to  only once you have enough reputation to become an [established user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user).

Comment: See my answer for a workaround that is possible for any user...