# Annotated posts page has empty HTML <title>

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, post-notices

https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts

The page source has an empty HTML title `<title></title>`

So the page shows up in my browser with the page URL as the title which looks messy and unfinished to me.

Same on other SE sites as well.

Comment: What the...? I didn't even know this existed

Comment: Same with its [noticed tab](http://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed).

Comment: @NickCraver there's a whole (double-secret, of course) [FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites) about pages like this.