# List of chat rooms with host stackoverflow.com is not the same as the actual list of rooms on stackoverflow.com chat itself

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

Generally `chat.<site>.com` redirects to `chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=<site>.com` and go for same thing but here you can check your self:

1. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/
2. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/?tab=site&host=stackoverflow.com

***Both are Different!***

If one visits https://chat.stackexchange.com/ and select site: StackOverflow, then it outputs [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/?tab=site&host=stackoverflow.com) and they miss rooms that are only listed by https://chat.stackoverflow.com/.

So, why does this happen? Is this a bug?

<sup>Note: I found this while [wandering](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3897186#3897186) for general chat-room at StackOverflow; see chat-discussion</sup>

Comment: It's because chat.SO is a different domain, I *think*.

Comment: This is normal. There are three separate chat servers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because they are completely different servers. We have three distinct chat servers on our network:

- Stack Overflow Chat (serving stackoverflow.com)
- Meta Chat (serving meta.stackexchange.com)
- Stack Exchange Chat (serving the rest of stackexchange.com)

Each of these chat servers is completely independent of each other and do not share the same rooms. When looking at Stack Overflow Chat, you will see all the rooms on Stack Overflow's chat servers. When looking at Stack Exchange Chat with the site filtered to Stack Overflow, you see any rooms on Stack Exchange Chat which have their parent site set to Stack Overflow. None of the rooms on Stack Overflow Chat will appear on Stack Exchange Chat, and none of the rooms on Stack Exchange Chat will appear on Stack Overflow Chat.

Comment: And the reasons for them being on different servers is performance?

Comment: I had not known that chat.stackoverflow.com has it's own server!

Comment: Are they actually different _physical_ servers, or just different domains with a different DB?

Comment: @forestdistrustsStackExchange Different domains with different databases, as [confirmed by a CM](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8658533#8658533).