# Why does Meta Stack Exchange have its own chat server?

Tags: discussion, chat, subdomains

Edit: [It looks like someone's already suggested merging chat for Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233734/351462)

---

[The proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270272/351462) explains that Stack Overflow has its own server due to sheer volume of traffic. **However, it doesn't explain why Meta Stack Exchange has its own server, having only 5 active rooms compared to Stack Exchange's 60 active rooms.**

To differentiate my question, I've changed my scope to specifically ask why ***Meta Stack Exchange*** has a separate chat server

---

### Original Post

The Stack Exchange network has [three separate servers/subdomains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264524/351462) for user chat.

- [**chat.stackoverflow.com**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) (Stack Overflow)
- [**chat.meta.stackexchange.com**](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) (Meta Stack Exchange)
- [**chat.stackexchange.com**](https://chat.stackexchange.com) (Super User, Server Fault, Arqade, Ubuntu, Mathematics, Web Applications, and all other SE sites)

**Why do Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange, and Stack Exchange use separate, independent chat servers instead of sharing one subdomain?**

---

Having separate servers means that ***users can have three separate chat accounts*** without even realizing. I only recently realized that, in addition to my [network](https://stackexchange.com/users/4030991/steven-vascellaro?tab=accounts) and per-site profiles, I also had separate accounts for [*Stack Overflow Chat*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3357935/steven-vascellaro#), [*Meta Chat*](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/351462/steven-vascellaro), and [*Stack Exchange Chat*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/262881/steven-vascellaro).

Profiles are fully separate with different profile settings, ignored user lists, favorited rooms, bookmarked conversations, and parent users. Each server has its own unique [users](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users), [rooms](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms), and [events](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=events).

I read a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264524/chat-stackoverflow-com-chat-stackexchange-com-rooms-tab-sitehost-stackover#comment860800_264527) speculating the servers may have been separated to improve performance. That reasoning could explain why Stack Overflow ([34 rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms)) is separate from Stack Exchange ([60 rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms)). But if performance were the reason, why separate Meta Stack Exchange? As of posting, Meta only has [5 active rooms](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms)

<sub>***Note**: This question is *not* about unique per-site domain URLs. See *[Why do some Stack Exchange sites have their own domain names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248453/351462)*</sub>

Comment: Still a dupe. balpha clearly mentions MSO/MSE: "other than then-MSO, now-MSE, which is always a special case", so instead of a whole separate question, we can ask him to elaborate in that existing answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The linked question only asks about Stack Exchange. While the answer mentions MSE is a special case, it doesn't explain *why* it's a special case

Comment: There isn't really any outstanding reason other than "because it's Meta." Meta has long had a history of "just because" features.

Comment: So like I said, I don't think this deserves a separate question.

Comment: @animuson Would it be acceptable to submit a separate feature request to have Meta chat merged with general SE?