# Meta chatroom rep different from site chatroom rep

Tags: support, reputation, chat

If you type a few lines one after the other in chat, you can see your site-wide reputation show up:

[image: Ask Ubuntu Chat]

Except in any https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com room:

[image: ShadowWizard's Den]

#### Why?  :-/

Comment: Because it's showing your rep on meta, which is 893 :)

Comment: `chat.meta != chat.stackexchange`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why?

> The Stack Exchange network has three separate servers/subdomains for
>   user chat.
>
> - chat.stackoverflow.com (Stack Overflow)
> - chat.meta.stackexchange.com (Meta Stack Exchange)
> - chat.stackexchange.com (Super User, Server Fault, Arqade, Ubuntu, Mathematics, Web Applications, and all other SE sites)

Source [Why does Meta Stack Exchange have its own chat server?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297299/why-does-meta-stack-exchange-have-its-own-chat-server)

That means your reputation is different on each server.