# Is there a way to find out if an accepted answer has been re-assigned?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, data-explorer

I am creating a query on data explorer in which I want to find out how many accepted answers were re-assigned (a different answer was accepted in the same question before, but a different question was accepted later) and has a score of 15. Is there a way to do that? Here is what I have so far:

```
-- Print out how many answers have accepted answers that 
-- have been re-assigned and have a score of fifteen.
-- Print them and the link to the answer owner

SELECT
  count(posts.AcceptedAnswerId) as [Accepted Answers]


FROM 
  posts

WHERE
      posts.postTypeId = 1
  and posts.Score >= 15
  -- Peramater for having the second accepted answer (accepted answer re-awarded)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might think that the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395335) seems to do that but renders a far by complete result.

```
with m_acc as (
select p.parentid as qid
, count(*) as cnt
from posts p
inner join votes  v on v.postid = p.id
where votetypeid = 1 -- AcceptedByOriginator
group by p.parentid
having count(*) > 1
)

select id as [Post Link]
     , score 
     , m_acc.cnt as [# times accept switch]
from posts p
inner join m_acc on qid = p.id
order by score desc
```

Remarkable enough only 57 questions seem to match that for Stack Overflow. Uncertain if that was a correct number, I checked [one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/126/timeline) which was correct so I assumed the other results are sound as well. But checking a couple of known positives from the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4220766#4220766) and [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26985525#26985525) it turns out that a lot of data is missing. The outcome here is probably due to invalid data.

Further investigation of two posts with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395357) only showed one accept record while the post timeline of both posts show **TWO** accept votes.

That leads me to conclude that the votes table is cleaned/sanitized to only contain the current accepted answer vote and not the history of those votes.

With that hope shattered on being able to answer your question I switched to looking at the `posthistory` table. Unfortunately that table doesn't have a record for accept votes either which leads to this unsatisfying answer:

You can't query for those questions because the data needed isn't available in any table available in SEDE.

Comment: Amazing! How did you get to the post timeline? I don't see a way to do it.

Comment: @CalebKleveter see this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76569/158100

Comment: @CalebKleveter The outcome is wrong, the data needed to query this probably shouldn't exist in SEDE but it does for 57 posts.

Comment: Oh, so the query you wrote actually doesn't  do what we thought it did?

Comment: right, I updated my answer to reflect that. You could post a feature request to get that added but you need to have a clear goal how that data helps the community