# Is it possible to get the rooms in which the user is pingable?

Tags: support, chat, ping

I know that it is possible to get the list of pingable users in a specific chatroom using 'rooms/pingable/{id}'. For example, this is what you get [for Tavern on meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/pingable/89). (IIRC this means that the user posted a message in that room at least once and they have visited the room not too long ago. I have to admit that I do not remember where exactly I have learned about this. Search here on meta shows that it is mentioned in this answer: [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566#76569).)

**Question:** Is it possible to get the same information "the other way round", i.e., to find out for a specific users in which rooms they are pingable?

Answer (score 4):

This is not going to give you *all* rooms in which a user is pingable, but a good start for finding a room to ping someone in could probably be the user's recent activity page: /users/id?tab=recent, for example [my MSE chat account](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802?tab=recent).

It shows the most recent rooms I've talked in, together with the timestamps of my recent chat activity. In general, if my last activity shown there is less than 7 days ago, you can safely assume I'm pingable in that room.

The rules for being pingable in chat are a bit more complicated: Being in a room without talking there can also make you pingable. So the recent activity tab is by no means exhaustive, but like I said, it's probably a good start to find a place where you can ping someone.

Comment: This is something I've been using. (Maybe I should have mentioned this also in the question.) In connection with the page with recent messages, it is probably useful to know that one can also see a list of older messages by manually adding `&page=2` to that URL. (And, of course, on can change the page number.) Here is your example link [modified in this way](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802?tab=recent&page=2).

Comment: @Martin True, but that shouldn't be all that needed when checking for recent activity with regards to whether someone is likely to be pingable, you don't want 'old' messages then ;) If you'd rather include this in your question as something you know but don't want, that's fine with me :)

Comment: @Martin Some of the rooms where the user is pingable which are not covered by their recent posting activity will be listed as rooms in the "currently in rooms" display on the [user's chat profile's "general tab"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802?tab=general). That list gives rooms they are currently in, which includes ones where they have never posted, but are pingable. The "frequently in rooms" display on the same page should also be checked, as it might give additional rooms the user has recently been in where they've previously, but not recently, posted.

Comment: To be complete (still missing any rooms recently visited, but not currently in, where they had previously posted at some time long ago), you'd need to get a list of rooms in which they've posted from the user's entire chat posting history and then individually check each room as to the user being pingable.

Comment: @Martin There are a couple of userscripts which add pagination buttons to the user's "recent" page: [Stack Exchange Chat History Pagination](https://github.com/spacemonaut/userscripts/tree/master/se-chat-user-history-pagination) and [Chat Pagination](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ChatPagination.user.js), which is also in Sam's [Chat Improvements](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ChatImprovements.user.js).